# How to get Error Message from a Google sheet cell using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to extract the error message from "A2" cell of Google sheet using the [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) Sheets v4 API method. I fond [this demo](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/8a596d235205ba443452aeb510220477) and modified the code to the snippet below. However it does not give the required output:

```js
function getErrorMessage(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  const value = sheet.getRange("A2").getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log(value);
  if (value == "#REF!") {
    const obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), {
      ranges: [sheet.getSheetName()],
      fields: "sheets",
    });
    const v = obj.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0];
    
    if (
      v.hasOwnProperty("effectiveValue") &&
      v.effectiveValue.hasOwnProperty("errorValue")
    ) {
      res.error = v.effectiveValue.errorValue;
      Logger.log(res.error);
    }
  }
}
```

The error in cell "A2" looks like this:

[image: Error]

I want to get the text saying:

> Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (1655).

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: First, I apologize that my blog was not useful for your situation. From your showing the modified script, I proposed a modification point. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, it seems that `res` is not declared. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
res.error = v.effectiveValue.errorValue;
Logger.log(res.error);
```

#### To:

```
const error = v.effectiveValue.errorValue;
Logger.log(error);
```

#### Note:

- As a test, when I put a formula of `=A2` into a cell "A2, and run the script by reflecting my proposed modification, `Logger.log(error);` showed `Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Settings.` in the log.

#### Added:

From your reply, how about the following modification? In this modification, the cell coordinate is directly used.

```js
function getErrorMessage() {
  const a1Notation = "'Sheet1'!A2";

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const value = ss.getRange(a1Notation).getDisplayValue();
  Logger.log(value);
  if (value == "#REF!") {
    Logger.log("I'm in")
    const obj = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ss.getId(), {
      ranges: [a1Notation],
      fields: "sheets(data(rowData(values(effectiveValue(errorValue)))))",
    });
    const v = obj.sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values[0];
    if (
      v.hasOwnProperty("effectiveValue") &&
      v.effectiveValue.hasOwnProperty("errorValue")
    ) {
      const error = v.effectiveValue.errorValue;
      Logger.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, however the error says: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`. You can see my tested result in my answer. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sure, here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1InCbCYdYBsrKtYbLVouk3Mnb-iV9ctTlNI45W-_DWiI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. From your reply, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it. When I tested this script using your provided Spreadsheet, `Unresolved sheet name 'mobile_numbers'.` is shown in the log.

Comment: thank you for the solution, it works as intended